# Authorize user by OpenID in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, authentication, authorization, idp, oidc-client-js

I use [oidc-client](https://github.com/joaojosefilho/vuejsOidcClient) in basic VueJs project, IDP server informations are correctly set in SecurityServices.js, here is my oidc config:

```
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager({    
  userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(undefined),
  authority: 'https://my.idpserver.com',
  client_secret: "f6ebb8fca6624a4e71c0c3",
  client_id: 'web.ui',
  redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:8081/authentication/login-callback',
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile web.ui.api offline_access',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:8081/authentication/logout-callback',
  silent_redirect_uri: 'https://localhost:8081/authentication/logout-callback',
  accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 10,
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  filterProtocolClaims: true,
  loadUserInfo: true
})
```

my program start and routes that has requireAuth metadata redirect to idp server after success full login get redirect to my website, here is my routes.js

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
    }
},
{
    path: '/authentication',
    component: loginCallBack,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'login-callback',
            name: 'LoginCallBackRoute',
            component: loginCallBack
        }
    ]
}
]
```

based on sample project and document after this redirect I should have authorized user that has access token to call other APIs, but after redirect i get this error in console: UserManager.getUser: user not found in storage

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "bookoffvue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-s

ervice serve --https --port 8081",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@splidejs/vue-splide": "^0.5.15",
    "@vueup/vue-quill": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "hooper": "^0.3.4",
    "oidc-client": "^1.11.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-oidc-client": "^1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "vue-persian-datetime-picker": "^2.10.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-select": "^3.16.0",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vueditor": "^0.3.1",
    "vuejs-countdown": "^0.2.1",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

this is screenshot of redirected user form IDP to my site:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> User not found in storage

You incorrect storage object used to persist User for currently authenticated user.

Remove `undefined` from `new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore(undefined)`.
`userStore` by default work with `session storage`.

If you want to use `local storage` just do it `new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })`

[Docs](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki)